# In Oracle SQL display multiple rows in single line

Tags: mysql, sql-server, oracle

I need a query for my requirement. I have a table called subject_details which has 2 fields.

```
student_Id  std_subject  
10               physics  
20               physics  
30               English  
10               Maths  
20               chemistry
```

I want to return records like:

```
 student_id       std_subject  
   10             physics,maths  
   20             physics,chemistry   
   30             English
```

Comment: You've tagged this for three different databases.  All three will have completely different solutions.  Which database are you actually using?

Answer (score 0):

For mysql, you can use [**group_concat**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)

```
select student_id, group_concat(std_subject)
from subject_detials
group by student_id
```

[**fiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1167b8/1)

Answer (score 0):

you can use group_concat in mysql.
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat
try this:

```
select student_id as student_id, group_concat(std_subject) as std_subject
from subject_detials
group by student_id
```

Answer (score 0):

**Oracle Solution**: ***Demo*** @ [***ORACLE Fiddle***](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/a23e8/5)

**Example 1**:

```
SELECT  
  "student_Id",
  RTRIM( XMLAGG( XMLELEMENT( R, "std_subject", ',' )
                .EXTRACT( '//text()' ) ),
         ',' ) subjects
FROM  student_subjects
GROUP BY "student_Id";
```

**Result 1**:

```
+------------+-------------------+
| student_id | subjects          |
+------------+-------------------+
|         10 | physics,Maths     |
|         20 | physics,chemistry |  
|         30 | English           |
+------------+-------------------+
```

**Example 2**:

```
SELECT 
  "student_Id",
  RTRIM( LISTAGG( "std_subject" || ',' ) 
         WITHIN GROUP( ORDER BY 1 ),
         ',' ) subjects
FROM  student_subjects
GROUP BY "student_Id";
```

**Result 2**:

```
+------------+-------------------+
| student_id | subjects          |
+------------+-------------------+
|         10 | Maths,physics     |
|         20 | chemistry,physics |  
|         30 | English           |
+------------+-------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

### In Oracle DB

Use LISTAGG function to do it ([LISTAGG ORACLE DOC](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10592/functions089.htm#SQLRF30030))
This will do what you want.

```
SELECT 
    student_Id
    ,LISTAGG(std_subject, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY std_subject) std_subject
FROM 
    student_subjects
GROUP BY 
    student_Id;
```